Problem with using a duashock 5 controller with pydualsense
First of all, I'm still quite inexperienced with Ubuntu.
I want to read the input from my DS5 controller using a Python script.
But when I try the example from this page , I get the following error.
File "/home/f-ubuntu/Dokumente/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    ds.init() # initialize controller
  File "/home/f-ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydualsense/pydualsense.py", line 108, in init
    self.device: hidapi.Device = self.__find_device()
  File "/home/f-ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydualsense/pydualsense.py", line 186, in __find_device
    dual_sense = hidapi.Device(
  File "/home/f-ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/hidapi.py", line 256, in __init__
    raise IOError("Could not open connection to device.")
OSError: Could not open connection to device.

Unfortunately I didn't find anything about it. Does anyone have an idea where my mistake is?
Im using Ubuntu 22.04, thank you so much!

Are you sure this script works on Ubuntu 20.04?

Yes. I also tried this one (https://github.com/yesbotics/dualsense-controller-python?tab=readme-ov-file#requirements), which is tested with 22.04 according to the doc , but I get the same error message

My question stands. Just because it works on 22.04 does not mean it runs on 20.04

What are the permissions. and ownership of the device? Please [edit] your Question and show us ls -l /dev/YourDevice. Do not reply via Add Comment.
